# showing error:Reverse for 'hompage' not found. 'hompage' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: django, django-forms

I added hompage function to my views.py and define spam namespace in url.py and also added spam app to setting.py file.now i want that after clicking 'detect' button which is in my template index.html i will redirect to same page but i am getting error:Reverse for 'hompage' not found. 'hompage' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

view.py file

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.urls import reverse
from django.http import HttpResponse,HttpResponseRedirect


def hompage(request):
  return render(request,'index.html')
```

url.py file

```
from django.conf.urls import url 
from . import  views
app_name = "spam"
urlpatterns=[
url(r'^',views.hompage)
]
```

index.html file

```
{% block content %}
<form action="{% url 'spam:hompage'  %}"  method="post"   >
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Detect">
{% endblock %}
```

installed app part of setting.py file

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'spam',
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no name for the *url* you are trying to call:

```
urlpatterns=[
url(r'^',views.hompage, name='homepage') # add name
]
```